# EF Extensions BulkDelete method doesn't delete with foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

I want to delete an entity which has foreign key relations with other tables.

But I get an error :

> The MERGE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Any suggestions how to make it work?

```
context.BulkDelete(entities);
```

Comment: You need to break references before deleting the entity. That seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically delete foreign key rows with EF Extensions for security reasons unless you have `DELETE CASCADE` enabled on your foreign key.

If you wish to delete, you will need to delete the foreign key data yourself first:

```
context.BulkDelete(entities.Select(x => x.ForeignKeyNavigation);
context.BulkDelete(entities);
```

or

```
context.MyForeignKeySets.DeleteRangeByKey(entities.Select(x => x.ForeignKeyID).Distinct());
context.BulkDelete(entities);
```

or

```
context.MyForeignKeySets.WhereBulkContains(entities.Select(x => x.ForeignKeyID).Distinct()).DeleteFromQuery();
context.BulkDelete(entities);
```

There is probably some other way to do it, but there is no automatic way to do it inside our library.